# achieve js setTimeout functionality in perl

Tags: multithreading, perl, settimeout

How do I achieve Javascript setTimeout functionality in Perl? This is the piece of javascript code I'm trying to write in Perl. Is this possible using threads?

```
alert("Event 1 occured");
setTimeout(function(){ alert("3 seconds elapsed"); }, 3000);
alert("Event 2 occured");
```

The output is:

```
 Event 1 occured
 Event 2 occured
 3 seconds elapsed
```

I have perl 5.18.2 and I'm on Mac OSX

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See the [alarm](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/alarm.html) function. Otherwise, consider looking at [threads.pm](https://metacpan.org/pod/threads) or , if you want to get feature parity with Javascript, one of the event loops, like [AnyEvent](https://metacpan.org/pod/AnyEvent) or [Mojo::IOLoop](https://metacpan.org/pod/Mojo::IOLoop) or [IO::Async](https://metacpan.org/pod/IO::Async).

With threads , your example would be:

```
use strict;
use threads;
print("Event 1 occured\n");
async {
    sleep 3;
    print "3 seconds elapsed\n";
};
print("Event 2 occured\n");
$_->join for threads->list; # to wait until all threads have finished
```

Answer (score 2):

There's no need for threads, and they're [not great anyway in Perl](https://perldoc.pl/threads#WARNING). You can use an event loop just like JavaScript does, there's just not any in the Perl core. Two popular and well supported event loop ecosystems are [IO::Async](https://metacpan.org/pod/IO::Async) and [Mojo::IOLoop](https://metacpan.org/pod/Mojo::IOLoop) (the event loop behind the Mojolicious web framework). The main difference is that unlike in JavaScript, the event loop isn't running until something starts it.

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use IO::Async::Loop;
print "Event 1 occurred\n";
my $future = IO::Async::Loop->new->delay_future(after => 3)->on_done(sub { print "3 seconds elapsed\n" });
print "Event 2 occurred\n";
$future->await; # run event loop until Future has been resolved

use strict;
use warnings;
use Mojo::IOLoop;
print "Event 1 occurred\n";
Mojo::IOLoop->timer(3 => sub { print "3 seconds elapsed\n" });
print "Event 2 occurred\n";
Mojo::IOLoop->start; # run event loop until no more events to wait for
```

Check out the [Mojolicious cookbook](https://metacpan.org/pod/Mojolicious::Guides::Cookbook#CONCEPTS) for a very high level overview of event loops and non-blocking code.

Comment: Re "*not great anyway in Perl*", Nah, that warning simply means you need to be aware that the threads are heavy to create.

Comment: That sounds not great to me. Also, it's more than that: it doesn't share variables by default, and many CPAN modules are not thread safe because threads are not widely used for these reasons.

Comment: That's all misinformation as well. 1) The fact that Perl variables aren't shared by default is irrelevant. If anything, it makes threads safer use than event loops like yours. As a programmer, you should be striving to reduce [coupling](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coupling_(computer_programming)) 2) Threads are very widely used. 3) The reason XS modules often don't support threads are for the opposite reason that you gave: The author didn't put in the effort to make it thread-safe, something that needs to be done because C vars *are* shared by default.

Comment: I don't wish to have a political argument with you. The fact that threads in Perl can be used correctly doesn't preclude them from being the biggest noob trap.

Comment: I don't see how that's possible. The whole reason the warning exists is because people on some IRC channel got tired of answering threads question. That never made sense because the alternatives (such as the IO loops you recommends) are so much more complex and error-prone.

Comment: Event loops are not an alternative, they are the correct way to wait on many I/O operations and timeouts at once. Threads are the correct way to perform multiple operations at once without forking. They are, however, incredibly obtuse to debug for reasons both related and unrelated to Perl's particular implementation. I invite you to join IRC and help all of the newbies try to use threads for trivial I/O tasks since we are so unwilling.

Comment: The OP didn't say anything about doing many IO ops at once. /// What makes you think I don't help people with their thread questions??

Comment: @Grinnz OK, I see that you don't like threads in Perl (or otherwise so it seems). What I don't get is: do you actually recommend event-based programming to the "newbies"?  Btw, ikegami has been a fantastic resource on threads (as on many, many other topics). You can piece together an "all-you-want-to-know" coverage from their answers and comments (here and elsewhere).

Comment: @Grinnz The above is mostly about this comment thread. I think that the post is fair (apart from the comment on threads), in this case. But good     luck to the uninitiated with understanding subtleties of future/promise workings, not to mention the event-based concepts and practice.

Comment: @zdim I haven't disputed any of that. And yes, I do recommend event-based programming to newbies when it's an appropriate solution, sure there's a learning curve but it's not like threading is a simple concept with no gotchas either; there's no getting around that asynchronous programming is unintuitive to start with. I only recently started posting here, but I'm happy to help anyone gain a better understanding, but I won't recommend Perl threads and don't have the experience to help anyone with them.